# The probability of throwing the same value (value not fixed) on a $N$-sided fair die at least $k$ times in a row at $n$ throws

Tags: probability

I only managed to solve this problem for a $2$-sided die (i.e., a coin) up to $k = 3$ (pathetic, I know).

With $f$ (at $k = 3$), I calculated the number of permutations which *do not* satisfy the above constraint.
\begin{align*}
f(n) &= 2h(n - 1) \\
h(0) &= 1 \\
g(0) &= 2 \\
h(n + 1) &= g(n) \\
g(n + 1) &= h(n) + g(n)
\end{align*}

Then, the solution is simple:

$$
\mathrm{P}(E_n) = 1 - \frac{f(n)}{2^n}.
$$

I acquired this result by observing some recursive properties of the properly restricted decision tree. The task was quite time-consuming and even for small modifications, it seemed like I'd have to do a lot of work again. So, I started wondering about the general solution to this problem, which is of course escapes me.

Thank you for your help! :)

P.S. This is my friend's solution to the restricted problem ($N = 2$, $k = 3$), which is also correct.

\begin{align*}
f(n) &= f(n - 1) + f(n - 2), \quad n > 2 \\
f(1) &= 2 \\
f(2) &= 4.
\end{align*}

In fact, my solution can be rewritten into this simpler form. Let $n > 2$. Then:

\begin{align*}
f(n) &= 2h(n - 1) = 2g(n - 2) = 2(h(n - 3) + g(n - 3)) \\
&= 2h(n - 3) + 2g(n - 3) = f(n - 2) + 2h(n - 2) = f(n - 2) + f(n - 1).
\end{align*}

For the cases where $n = 1$ or $n = 2$, we simply confirm with the original definition that, indeed, $f(1) = 2$ and $f(2) = 4$.

Comment: To clarify your question, are you fixing $x$ or are you asking for the probability of getting a run of length at least $k$ for any available number?  In other words, if you're rolling a $D6$ six times, are you asking for the probability of rolling at least three consecutive $3$s, or are you asking for the probability of rolling *any* number three times in a row?

Comment: @RobertShore I should have clarified... $x$ is not fixed. Any sequence of values will do. I will edit the title to make that clearer.

Comment: @RobertShore \*That is, any sequence of *identical* values will do.

Comment: I feel that a solution to this will involve a horrible $k$-fold application of the inclusion-exclusion principle.

Comment: @gandalfbalrogslayer Thanks, I might look into it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*New notation:* When you roll an $m$-sided die $n$ times, what is the probability some value appears at least $k$ times in a row?

We want to count the number of sequences $(x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n)$, such that each $x_i\in \{0,1,\dots,m-1\}$, and some value appears $k$ times consecutively. Equivalently, we can count sequences where no value appears $k$ times consecutively, then subtract from $m^n$.

For each $i\in \{1,\dots,n-1\}$, define
$$
d_i=x_{i+1}-x_{i}\pmod m
$$
First of all, note that the correspondence
$$
(x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n)\mapsto (x_1,d_1,d_2,\dots,d_{n-1})
$$
is a bijection. You can uniquely recover the $(x_1,\dots,x_n)$ sequence from the $(x_1,d_1,\dots,d_{n-1})$ sequence, via $x_i=x_1+d_1+\dots+d_{i-1}\pmod m$.

Secondly, the sequence $(x_1,\dots,x_n)$ contains $k$ consecutive equal values if and only if the sequence $(d_1,\dots,d_{n-1})$ contains $k-1$ consecutive zeroes. We have reduced the situation to a simpler problem:

> How many sequences of length $n-1$ with symbols in $\{0,1,\dots,m-1\}$ contain no $(k-1)$ consecutive zeroes?

If you let $a_n$ be the number of sequences of length $n$ with no $(k-1)$ consecutive zeroes, then $a_n$ obeys the recurrence
$$
a_n=(m-1)[a_{n-1}+a_{n-2}+\dots+a_{n-k+1}]\qquad \text{when }n\ge k-1
$$
The base cases for the recurrence are $a_n=m^n$ when $0\le n\le k-2$. This can be seen by conditioning on the length of the run of zeroes at the end of the sequence. I cannot give a formula for $a_n$ in general. You can find a formula by applying the method of [solving constant coefficient linear recurrences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_recurrence_with_constant_coefficients), but it will in general be a messy sum of powers of irrational or complex numbers.

Putting this altogether, the number of sequences with no $k$ consecutive equal symbols is
$$
m\cdot a_{n-1},
$$
because choosing $(x_1,\dots,x_n)$ is equivalent to choosing $(x_1,d_1,\dots,d_{n-1})$, and there are $m$ choices for $x_1$, and $a_{n-1}$ choices for $(d_1,\dots,d_{n-1})$.